# Not showing logs in report portal based on log level (WARN, INFO, DEBUG, etc)

Tags: karate, reportportal

We have karate tests integration with report portal setup. we are trying to show logs in report portal based on logging configuration level [ fatal>error>warn>info>debug>trace ], but it's not working as per required. It is showing log and code under debug level even when we have log level set as "INFO" in logback-test.xml or log4j2.xml. We have same code in both file. Same xml file code is working with TestNg.

Hare is snapshot.
D point to DEBUG log and I pointing to INFO log, Why this INFO logs showing under DEBUG ? Log slider in report portal pointing to INFO in snapshot.
[image]

**log4j2.xml or logback-test.xml code:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration packages="com.epam.ta.reportportal.log4j.appender" status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%throwable"/>
        </Console>
        <ReportPortalLog4j2Appender name="ReportPortalAppender">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%throwable"/>
        </ReportPortalLog4j2Appender>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="ReportPortalAppender"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.epam.reportportal.service" level="WARN" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="ReportPortalAppender"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.epam.reportportal.utils" level="WARN" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="ReportPortalAppender"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>bintray</id>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/epam/reportportal</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
           
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>agent-java-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-model</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
            <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-gatling</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am referring to sendLog() methods from https://github.com/workwithprashant/karate-reportportal-demo/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/dell/reporting/reportportal/ScenarioReporter.java

Please suggest any solution for the consolidating logs in report portal as per mentioned log level in log4j2.xml or logback-test.xml.

Comment: this is absolutely not a priority for us (the karate project) please contribute code or knowledge to the community or you are welcome to look for other tools